# How to run pytest for only pull requests changes using github actions

Tags: python, github, pytest, github-actions

I want to run pytest for only those tests which have changes made to them or which are in the PR.

For example I have a repo called Utils.

```
Utils
|
|--utils
│   │
│   ├───__init__.py
│   └───add.py
|
|--tests
  │
  ├───__init__.py
  └───test_add.py
```

Now if I add a new file to utils - sub.py and its corresponding test file to tests - test_sub.py. Then I want the github actions to test only the sub.py function not the ones that have no change.

I have attached the workflow that I'm using currently. This will run tests for both test_add.py and test_sub.py. I don't want that. Please help me fix this.

```
name: Python tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install flake8 pytest
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
      - name: Lint with flake8
        run: |
          # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
          flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
          # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
          flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest
```

Comment: You could use the `on: push` with the subtype `paths` ou `paths-ignore` informing which paths or not should trigger your workflow. Did you try this solution? [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore)

Comment: In the starting I was running tests on both pull request and push. Then I removed the Push because I just want to run tests on the PR and for that PR only.

Comment: I didn't got your paths-ignore point because every tests is present in the tests directory. No other subdirectory. So what path should I ignore.

Comment: Also I can't ignore some test files also with this way because every test file has the same naming convention test_*.py. So Can you share some other solution?

Comment: Understood. In that case you won't be able to achieve what you want with a native solution, you will always have to trigger the workflow using for example `on: pull_request: paths: '**/test_*.py.' ` and then filter the files to check which one are new to run the pytest command to for the new tests. Maybe using a [path-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) or a [get-diff action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-diff-action#usage) could help.